# input_dim, output_dim not working in updated keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras

i am doing this online course on udemy and everything works fine but when i try to intialize the first hidden layer it gave the following error

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'.
```

then I did the ctrl+I on the spyder and chnged the output_dim and init arguments but i dont know what to replace others with ..

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

#initializing the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

#adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units =6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform' , activation = 'relu', input_dim =11 ))

#adding the second layer

classifier.add(Dense(Output_dim = 6 , kernel_initializer = 'uniform' , activation = 'relu'))
```

should work fine with no error

Comment: Please do spend a minute to see how to properly format your code blocks (done it for you this time); plus, question has nothing to do with `spyder` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced by `keras`).

Comment: ok @desertnaut . I have multiple negative votes . please atleast remove your negative vote if you dont wanna give me a plus one :)

Comment: and thanks for the edit xx

Answer (score 0):

In a `Dense` layer, the number of units is equivalent to the output dimensionality. However, the argument `Output_dim` does not exist. So, replace `Dense(Output_dim=6, ...)` with `Dense(units=6, ...)` (or even just `Dense(6, ...)`).

Answer (score 0):

In the new documentation of Dense function output_dim is replaced by units, and the input_dim is replaced by input_shape. However in the input_shape argument you have to specify a tuple.

Eg:

Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer

`classifier.add(Dense(units=6, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'uniform', input_shape = (11, )))`

Adding the second layer

`classifier.add(Dense(units = 6 , kernel_initializer = 'uniform' , activation = 'relu'))`

Answer (score 0):

## Add the first ANN layers (Input and Hidden Layers)

`classifier.add(Dense(units=6, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform', input_dim = 11))`

## Adding the second hidden layer

`classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))`